# How to set background color of the textbox portion of a combobox when dropdown style is DropDownList in .NET?

Tags: .net, drop-down-menu, combobox, backcolor

I'm coding in VB.NET.  I have a requirement that my combobox display as mandatory, which means the backcolor must be yellow.  The dropdownstyle is DropDownList so the user can type in the textbox field of the combobox but only find the items in the combobox.

If I set the backcolor of the combobox to yellow, the dropdown panel of the combobox is yellow, but I am unable to get the textbox field to display with a yellow background.

This only appears to be a problem when the dropdownstyle is DropDownList.

I've looked at many questions about this online but they mostly address the dropdown panel, not the textbox field, or else they are WPF or Web solutions.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember right, that's an issue with the DropDownList, but I'm not sure. But if that's the case and you want it yellow anyway, you can put a textbox in top of the combobox and display the value of it.

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          ΤextBox.Text = ((YourType)ComboBox.SelectedItem).YourValue;
       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried that but there's one problem - the textbox does not look like it has focus.  The cursor doesn't appear in it so the user can't tell that she's in it, and that's not going to be acceptable.

Comment: You can set the cursor property to arrow, from the properties or from the designer class.
this.YourTextBoxName.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;

Comment: In order for the user to be able to type in the textbox, but select from the combobox, focus has to be on the combobox behind the textbox.  So how do I get the cursor to appear in the textbox?  To make this work, in the Gotfocus of the textbox, I set focus to the combobox, and in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox, I display the selected item's text in the textbox.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that you want the user to type, I thought you wanted them to select from the drop down with the mouse. What about if you made only a textbox with autocomplete from the allowed values and in the validation, check if the value that has been entered is one from the allowed ones?

Comment: From a development point of view, that sounds like a cool idea.  But it doesn't allow the user to open the dropdown and see what the possibilities are - they may not know the code they want.

Comment: Well you can do both. The textbox in top of the dropdown, so tan the user can click on the down-arrow and then display the selected value in the textbox and also give the autocomplete list to the textbox in case someone wants to write and validate after.